# rm is unable to remove file even id file appears through ls

Tags: unix

Hello I have a directory containing following files:

```
bomble@master:/mnt/store/test$ ls -lrt /mnt/store/ChemAlive/utilities/
total 46623
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    63168 Feb  9 13:48 rungms
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      285 Feb 11 10:18 runCP2K.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46535066 Feb 11 10:22 cp2k.popt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      108 Feb 11 10:22 cp2kend
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      206 Feb 11 10:22 cp2kendhess
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      285 Feb 11 10:22 cp2kstart
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       34 Feb 11 10:23 gamessdisphf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       45 Feb 11 10:23 gamesssolvt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      193 Feb 11 10:23 gamessstart
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1110176 Feb 11 10:23 mopac5021mn.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      564 Feb 11 10:23 mopacgeom
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       95 Feb 11 10:23 nwchemend
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      197 Feb 11 10:23 nwchemwaterend
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    25110 Feb 11 10:24 rmsperl.pl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       60 Feb 11 10:24 scriptjmol
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       15 Feb 11 10:24 triatomicend.mop
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      224 Feb 11 10:30 gamessstarthf
```

I want to remove rungms that appears. If I try it fails:

```
bomble@master:/mnt/store/test$ sudo rm  /mnt/store/ChemAlive/utilities/rungms 
rm: cannot remove '/mnt/store/ChemAlive/utilities/rungms': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you attached results of `ls -l` command. It reports more details about files.

Comment: @nolexa See edit but I am sure it is not a problem of rigths

Comment: I would check the following possibilities: the media is mounted with read only access, the media is physically write protected

Comment: can you create a dummy file in that directory and then remove it?

Comment: yes I can it is jus this files that is having a problem

Comment: Have you checked that the file really exists and you can read it? Try to `cat` the file. It is possible that the file system is corrupted and the directory lists a file that is no longer there.

Comment: It is an executable so I couldn't cat it but I can't execute it anymore it is saying it does not exist.

Comment: Try using bash filename completion to see if perhaps there are invisible characters in the filename. That is, `cd` to the directory, then type `rm r` and without hitting Enter, hit tab twice and see if the list of filenames expands to `run` (since two files start with that text). If that works, hit a `g`, then hit tab again, and see if the rest of the file appears.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this question does not quite fit this forum and the `Unix` tag because it's not about programming. It should have been asked at [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) forums.

Anyway, according to your description, the directory seems to be corrupt. You can try the following recipe shared at https://superuser.com/questions/197605/delete-a-corrupt-file-in-linux:

1. Rename your directory.
2. Recreate the original directory (empty).
3. Copy other files back to it.
4. Delete the directory containing that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has a non-printable character or space at the end of the file name.

How about just do `sudo rm  /mnt/store/ChemAlive/utilities/rung*`